# Inkscape. Flip vertical

Tags: inkscape

[image]When I select the text tool and click and drag the text appears flipped horizontally. I can solve it going to Object > Flip horizontal. But I would like to understand why does it happen from the beginning and how to solve it. I have gone to Preferences > Text and I do not see any way to solve it.

Comment: Without ever having used inkscape… are you dragging left-to-right or right-to-left when this happens?

Comment: @Tetsujin. I drag left to right. But on the other direction, the problem is the same

Comment: I am an Inkscape user, but I don't know what you mean at all. Why are you clicking and dragging the text, and what are you trying to achieve when this happens? Perhaps you could show a screenshot to show what is happening. It might help.

Comment: Just in case, check if VIEW -> ORIENTATION -> FLIP HORIZONTAL is activated (inkscape 1.0).

Comment: What Juancho says and: if you are working in a file that was created from a pdf, create a new layer and transfer all content into that layer, or copy-paste all content into a new document (known issue with pdf files that come with lots of weird transformations).

Comment: @Billi Kerr. I select text tool (F8) One-click to write text. Click and drag to create a text block. How do you create a text block? is there any other way?

Comment: @Juancho. I have a Mac. I think it is the last version. In Menu > View I do not see any Orientation. I have Flip Horizontal in Oject and it is not activated by default

Comment: @Moini. The file was not created from a pdf

Comment: Inkscape 1.0 does have the orientation setting in the view menu. Please check your version number in Help > About and also provide a sample file.

Comment: @Moini. Version. 1.0beta1 In View I do not see orientation. I am in a mac 10.15.5. How can I provide a sample file?

Comment: You could update to 1.0, to get a stable supported Inkscape version. The Canvas orientation item should be there even in the beta. You can attach a file to your post when you edit it.

Comment: I have updated and I see the same problems. I give up.

Comment: I've voted to close this question now, as I can't recreate the problem. Sorry about that. Also tech support is generally off-topic, and you appear to have already exhausted all the guesses.

Answer (score 2):

The only case when I see this behaviour while using Inkscape is when you have already entered some text, which you then grab and stretch horizontally. The text will flip once it moves beyond the midpoint of the textbox.

[image: Is this what you mean to say.]

Comment: Seems to me like thats working as intended

Comment: @sciencejedi.  the problem hapens to me when I create new text from scratch. Not when I have already entered some text.

Comment: That is quite odd. Have you fixed it already? If yes, then we all would love to know what caused this. Thank you!